# Flutter Ignore Coverage Comments Do Not Work All The Time

Tags: flutter, dart, integration-testing, code-coverage

```
// coverage:ignore-line
// coverage:ignore-start
// coverage:ignore-end
```

Do not work always.

I am using the above comments to notify the tester to ignore the lines from test coverage to achieve 100% code coverage. But these comments work only at someplace and behave strangely.

I tried all the ways to ignore the line from my code but failed to get the expected result.

[image: //coverage:ignore-line not working]

[image: coverage range not working]

In the above images, you can see that even after adding `//coverage:ignore-line` and `// coverage:ignore-start // coverage:ignore-end` the report is not able to ignore the line and it is shown in red color. This decreases the code coverage percentage.

I have also noticed that it fails when there is a lambda function or multiple classes and datatypes.

How can we achieve 100% code coverage? What can be a workaround to this?

Below is my flutter and dart version

```
Flutter 2.10.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 5f105a6ca7 (3 weeks ago) • 2022-02-01 14:15:42 -0800
Engine • revision 776efd2034
Tools • Dart 2.16.0 • DevTools 2.9.2
```

PS: I have followed and read almost all the GitHub discussions but still nothing.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/76544

https://github.com/dart-lang/coverage/issues/162

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/61408

https://github.com/dart-lang/coverage/issues/340

and many more

Comment: Read this github discuss and try to follow their instruction , it might help you to some extent!!https://github.com/dart-lang/coverage/issues/330

Comment: I read almost all the GitHub discussions but still nothing.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/76544
https://github.com/dart-lang/coverage/issues/162
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/61408
https://github.com/dart-lang/coverage/issues/340